# How can I find out, check and change my $db_host, user, pass, name in mysql workbench?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$db_host = "";
$db_user = "";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "";
```

I have to fill out these, so I wanted to check but I used 'ampps' to install mysql.
so I couldn't find info in my database.

where should I check in below pic?
[mysql wrokbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maWgq.png)
[wrokbench2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAWlh.png)

Comment: If you installed mysql you should know the username and password. If you did not, then ask the person who did. If you forgot the username and password details, then reset the password.

Answer (score 0):

Detault mysql login credentials in AMPPS are :
Username : root
Pass : mysql

You can create a new database using phpMyAdmin :
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/